# On-line science fiction short about super powerful computer virus?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this one online within the last ten years; it involved a virus that got completely out of control and took over all sorts of equipment—including radio equipment (which doesn't make sense but there you go).

The final defeat of the virus came when the computer scientists simply asked "Bart" (?), the computer program they had been training up to a point of sentience, to write an anti-virus to defeat the super virus.

The same author had other short stories on the same website, including:

- A time travel story with alternate dimensions where after traveling far back in the past, one of the main characters argues that it would be logically impossible for him to blow up the earth.  When he attempts to prove his point, the earth blows up.  (But that's not the end.)
- A story where after a quantum computer is successfully used to simulate the entire universe, the technicians discover that unfortunately they are only themselves within a simulation—and probably not only one layer deep!
- A long essay with a description of "What if music were taught in schools the way we taught math?"  Memorize and copy sheet music, never actually play any music, turn everyone off of the subject completely, etc.

Does anyone recognize these descriptions?  Who is the author; what is the website?  Google seems unhelpful since I don't remember any story titles or character names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha, found it just after I posted!

- The virus story — ["Tyro"](https://qntm.org/tyro)
- The time travel story — ["The Four and a Halfth Planet"](https://qntm.org/destroyed1)
- The quantum computer story — ["I don't know, Timmy, being God is a big responsibility"](https://qntm.org/responsibility)

These stories are all by Sam Hughes.

Not sure where on the site is the article about music, but I'm sure I'll find it if I dig.

Comment: Please expand the answer with the name of the author and the actual names of the stories. It makes the answer more useful to other people without clicking the links, and makes sure it will remain useful even if the linked site goes down.

Comment: The last one is Lockhart's Lament - https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf