# Book about a computer virus transmitted via sound

Tags: story-identification, books, virus

When I was in high school, back in the mid-90s, I read a book about a world that had been infected by a virus that enhanced technology, could turn speakers to mics, etc. It was even transmitted via sound. I don't remember a whole lot more, but I do remember that there was a simulaition of Doom involved in an attempt to defeat it.

EDIT: Tyro is too new, I graduated in May of 2001, this would have been 1997-1998 when I read it. I don't remember it enhancing anyone, just technology. Not sure why one of the main characters fought it in Doom, but that and the modification of tech stand out.

Comment: Did the virus affect people or just computers?

Comment: A bit similar to Tyro https://qntm.org/tyro: "Tyro jumped to the plane by an audible radio transmission, and took over the plane's in-flight systems", possible duplicate for https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128193/on-line-science-fiction-short-about-super-powerful-computer-virus

Comment: Captain Crunch phone whistler.

Comment: There have been a few cases (so far mainly theoretical) of computer viruses transmitting via an "air gap" of sound.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots transmitting data via an audio modem doesn't seem so theoretical to me. Would be interesting to read about such a case though